# Can you store a HTML element class name into an array then call it to run in JQuery attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to store an HTML class name like **class="group01"** into an array then call it to run a jQuery property like **.show()**? Below I wrote an example of what I'm trying to do. I'm kinda so-so when it comes to javascripting arrays.

Example:

```html
<div class="stuff group01"></div>
<div class="stuff group02"></div>
<div class="stuff group03"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.stuff').hide();
        const classArray = ['.group01','.group02','.group03'];
        var pNum = '1; //will change with a dropdown input element

        switch (pNum) {
            case pNum = '1':
                $(classArray[0]).show();
                $(classArray[1][2]).hide();
            break;
            case pNum = '2':
                $(classArray).show();
                $(classArray[0][2]).hide();
            default:
                $('.group03').after('<p>ERROR</p>');
        }
    });        
</script>
```

End result should be that the other div elements with the classname of `group01` etc. should hide according to what dropdown input is selected.

If this is not possible, how would you go about making something thats similar to this logic? I tried looking around but no one really seem to have an answer to this particular situation.

Comment: you don't have multidimensional array $(classArray[0][2]).hide(); hence this syntax is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classArray[0], classArray[1], classArray[2]` are your only valid items.

`classArray[0][2]` would imply there is another array within `classArray[0]`.

Example

```js
const classArray = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], "Item 1", "Item 2"] 

classArray[0][2] => 'a3'
classArray[1][0] => error  
classArray[2] => 'Item 2'
```

You'll need to separately hide each individual item.

Providing just `classArray` to `$()` is not valid as it is expecting a `string` not an `array`

---

You can convert your array to a string and pass that value to `$()`

Example 1

```js
const knownClasses = [".item-1", ".item-2", ".item-3"]

// You can use .slice(startIndex, endIndex) to slice a portion of the array
const items = knownClasses.join()

console.log(items) // `.item-1 .item-2 .item-3`

$(items).hide
```

Example 2

```js
function determineVisibility(classArr, acceptedSet) {
    const showClasses = [];
    const hideClasses = [];
    classArr.forEach(c => {
      if (acceptedSet.includes(c)) {
        showClasses.push(c);
      } else {
        hideClasses.push(c);
      }
    });

    return { showClasses: showClasses.join(), hideClasses: hideClasses.join() };
}

const classArr = [".class-1", ".class-2", ".class-3", ".class-4"];
const acceptedSet = [".class-1", ".class-4"];

const { showClasses, hideClasses } = determineVisibility(classArr, acceptedSet);

$(showClasses).show();
$(hideClasses).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class-1">1</div>
<div class="class-2">2</div>
<div class="class-3">3</div>
<div class="class-4">4</div>
<div class="class-5">5</div>
```

Comment: good way to work around it but what if I wanted to show ".item-1" and ".item-3" but hide ".item-2"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic example. Add an event listener to buttons and get the value when clicked. Use that value to show the correct class value you want to get.

```js
const cool = document.getElementsByClassName("cool");
for (let i = 0; i < cool.length; i++)
{
    // add event listener to all buttons 
    // which calls a function passing value of button
    cool[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        calling(this.value);
    });
}  

function calling(number)
{
    const awesome = document.getElementsByClassName("awesome");
    for (let i = 0; i < awesome.length; i++)
    {    
        if (i == number) {  
            awesome[number].style.cssText = "display: block";  
        } else {
            awesome[i].style.cssText = "display: none";
        }
    }       
}
```

```html
<button class="cool" value="0">Apple</button>
<button class="cool" value="1">Banana</button>
<button class="cool" value="2">Orange</button>
    
<div class="awesome" style="display: none;">apple</div>
<div class="awesome" style="display: none;">banana</div>
<div class="awesome" style="display: none;">orange</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This won't work as you expect, since the switch executes once the script is loaded. If you're just getting started at javascript, I'd advice against using jQuery, since you can pick some wierd syntax and believe it's standard javascript when it's not.

Provided you add a [data-option] attribute to each of your dropdown options, i.e.

```
<li data-option="1">option 1</li>
```

In vanilla javascript you could use something like this:

```
elementsToHideOrShow = document.querySelectorAll('.stuff');
document.querySelectorAll('[data-option]').forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener('click', function(){
        elementsToHideOrShow.forEach(element => 
            element.classList.toggle('hidden', !element.classList.contains('group0' + option.dataset['option']))
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: this is, considering you're using something like bootstrap, then use the class to hide elements.